# mongodb unwated removal of an empty field on update

Tags: php, mongodb

Currently i run a mongo query that looks similar to the following:

```
$query = array(
    'user_id' => $this->getUserId(),
    'name'    => $this->getName()
);
```

I check to see if the record exists, if it does i want to update it, if not create it.

```
if(is_null($this->getId())) {
    $query['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->collection->insert($query);
    $this->setId($query['_id']);
    return true;
} else {
    $conditions = array(
     '_id' => new \MongoId($this->getId())
    );
    return $this->collection->update($conditions, $query);
}
```

currently, if the record is new a **'created'** date field is added. However when i run an update mongoDb appears to bring back the correct record but removing the created field, instead of just leaving it as it is.

Ive tried adding `'created' => $this->getCreated()` to the **$query** and also to the **$conditions**, both proving unsuccessful. Is there something obvious im doing wrong thats causing the field i want left alone to delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your problem, I would suggest re-trying "'created' => $this->getCreated() to the $query" provided your model has a created property defined, and your getter method is working, then this should use the current date on an insert, and the pre-set property value on update.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your `$query` value. It is a common beginner mistake.

Placing a whole query document into update like so:

```
$query = array(
    'user_id' => $this->getUserId(),
    'name'    => $this->getName()
);
```

Without any operators will actually REPLACE the original document with this one.

Instead to `$set` those fields to a new value you should use `$set`:

```
$query = array('$set' => array(
    'user_id' => $this->getUserId(),
    'name'    => $this->getName() )
);
```

This should give you the effect you desire.

Comment: when i used the '$set' => array the create stopped working, is $set purely for update, so id have to duplicate my query code?

Comment: @gardni Yes, atomic operators don't work on insert, though you could change it to a upsert, that would work